# Get files in a directory not containing certain pattern with FileInfo object

Tags: vb.net, io

I have this files in a directory:
User1_File1.pdf
User1_File2.pdf
User1_File2-1.pdf
User1_File2-2.pdf
User1_File3.pdf
User1_File4.pdf

I'm working in vb .Net. Using the **GetFiles** method of the **FileInfo** object I want to get all the files **NOT** containing the **"-"** character in the name. How can I do this?

```
    Dim diDirectorio As New DirectoryInfo(sPath)
    Dim fiArchivos() As FileInfo = diDirectorio.GetFiles(sFilter & "*.*")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Not fileName.Contains("-") Then
'Get code
End If
```

Post your code and I can implement this feature for you.

Comment: Question edited, I added the two relevant lines of code for this question. Currently with GetFiles I get all the files in the directory that have certain pattern (usaully the name of the user). If I understand your suggestion, then I have to loop throught the array with the filenames and manually left out the ones with "-" on the name, right?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old now but this works too...

```
dim dirInfo as new io.DirectoryInfo("DirectoryPath")
dim files as io.fileinfo() = dirInfo.GetFiles("pattern").Where(Function(x) Not x.Name.ToLower.Contains("exclude pattern")).toArray
```